# Symbol for Gtalk or Skype to add in resume contact

Tags: symbols

Is there a way to add any symbol for gtalk or skype next to my ID name?. We have symbols for phone, mail etc. Anything similar for this ?

UPDATE:

SOLUTION : FONTAWESOME package gives all the social linked symbols. Thanks.

Comment: This is off topic.

Comment: Yes: take their symbol (if allowed) and scale it down to the size you need.  The [fontawesome](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome) package has many 'modern' symbols; not sure about those, however.